# Google map api key` in android

Tags: android, google-maps

I need to show the google map in webview application the page will be stored local, and will get the cordinates from the server and will use google map to show the location, so my question is: do i need the android api for the map to work or the normal website api for this?
In my openion i think i have to register the application and get the app api.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just accessing google map in webview, or default map application on device, you don't need an api key, you need api key, in case you need to access MapView in your application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use WebView and MapView:

For WebView you Do Not need api key:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

For MapView you need map api key:

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html.here
http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android